# "$n^{th}$ partial sum"

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Does the phrase, "$n^{th}$ partial sum" refer to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)$ or $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)$?

Comment: The sum of the first n terms. So the first one, if beginning at zero.

Comment: I would have it refer to the second.  That does mean that the initial partial sum you'll come across would be $\sum\limits_{k=0}^0f(k) = f(0)$, which you might then call the "Zero'th partial sum."  Some people don't like that, hence your question.  It is in many cases this very point that helps contribute to some people not liking to start to count from zero and leads to some people writing $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ rather than $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$, why some people start writing sequences as $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ instead of $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$, etc...

Comment: The end result is that both are used, and if it becomes relevant then clarification should be added as to which you mean.  Regardless of whether you end at $n-1$ or end at $n$ if you want to talk about the "n'th partial sum" in some way without being ambiguous, you can still very cleanly avoid the issue by instead talking about the function $S(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)$ and just talk about $S(n)$ without referring to it as the "$n$'th partial sum" or the "$n+1$'st partial sum."

Comment: @JMoravitz Given a question to "find an explicit expression for the n-th partial sum" of a given series and no further clarification, do you suppose a professor/examiner would accept either interpretation?

Comment: I would say yes, though again, in order to avoid the issue and to make it clear which interpretation you are using, I would again avoid using the phrase "the $n$'th partial sum" and instead use the notation $S(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)$ and talk about the explicit expression for $S(n)$.  Alternatively, you could always ask for clarification from the proctor/professor.  Questions like those are more than welcome, even during an exam.  What is being tested is your ability to do math, not your ability to guess as to the linguistic interpretation of certain ambiguous phrases.

Comment: @JMoravitz OK, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer to your question is "Yes." :P

A more useful answer is that *either* sum could reasonably be called the "$n$-th partial sum"—this phrase is more descriptive than technical, and it is does not have a universally agreed upon technical definition.  Some authors prefer to start counting at zero; others at one.  Indeed any one of
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k), \qquad
\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k), \qquad\text{or}\qquad
\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) $$
could reasonably be called the $n$-th partial sum.  Moreover, the distinction between these sums is rarely terribly important or significant—the precise form of the $n$-th partial sum is usually far less important than the limit.  That being said, if I were forced to pick a side, my own preference would be to call the latter sum the "$n$-th partial sum".

Of course, if it really does become necessary to work with the partial sums directly, one should make clear exactly what is meant.  For example, write

> **Definition:**  Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, and define
>   $$S(n) := \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k). $$
>   The value $S(n)$ is the *$n$-th partial sum*.

Finally, I would like to reiterate [JMoravitz's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476392/nth-partial-sum#comment7147182_3476392):  it can never hurt to ask for clarification.  If you see this in lecture notes or on an exam, it is reasonable to politely ask the instructor or proctor for clarification.  In this setting the goal is to learn—if confusion about notation is preventing your from learning, or preventing you from demonstrating your understanding, then you should absolutely ask for a more precise statement.